# Creating a File System, need C advice

Tags: c, unix, filesystems

I am building this file system in C.  At the moment I am on the first step of the assignment which is just to create a simple file system that works in memory.  My question is more based around C than it is around a Unix File System.  I am trying to "emulate" a raw disk.  I have the following structure:

```
struct disk {
    void *data;
    unsigned int numOfBlocks;
};
```

Let's pretend a block on this disk will be 512 Bytes (like the original Unix file system).  I have some functions defined to create a disk, read from a disk, and write to a disk.  It is then my job to implement the various things such as data blocks, i-node blocks, the super block etc.

Look at the `void *data` variable above.  I want this to be a two dimensional array.  It should be an array of block arrays.  So...what makes the most sense to be is to use something like this.

`unsigned char *data[30][512]; // Assuming the disk holds 30 blocks of 512 bytes each`

Here comes the question: If I have other structures defined to represent an i-node, a super block, or a data block, and each also has a `struct` size of 512 bytes, how can I properly cast this `unsigned char *` to the i-node `struct`, or the data `struct`, etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question.

From what you say:
`My question isn't how to access the characters in the data variable...it's how to take a 512 byte array of unsigned char for instance and convert it to some other type of struct that is 512 bytes long.`

If you have:

```
unsigned char block[512];
```

and:

```
//total struct size: 512 bytes
struct something {
     //members here
};
```

You could do this:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct something *ptr;
    ptr = block;
    return 0;
}
```

You can just use the array bytes to hold the structure data. To avoid warnings, cast the address:

```
ptr = (struct something *)block;
```

After you assigned memory to the pointer you can use it as you normally would.

note: I may be wrong since I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

`void` is point to anything, so if you have control of what `void *` means, than the definition you have is enough.

To access `data` as a two dimensional array, you just need to cast the type `((char (*)[512])data`
or

```
char *array[512] = data;
byte = array[x][y];
```

the compiler do not need to know the size of the second dimension, it is your responsibility to make sure your program will never access an invalid location.

Comment: My question is't how to access the characters in the data variable...it's how to take a 512 byte array of `unsigned char` for instance and convert it to some other type of `struct` that is 512 bytes long.